# Unit Test Mock for Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: java, rest-client, spring-restcontroller, webservices-client, springmockito

A we are using Spring Boot Rest Api for service calls.
We can use Junit for unit test cases I guess.
But need to know other suitable tool or framework to mock Unit Test for Spring Boot Rest Api () other than junit.

Comment: why? you just can test and mock everything with junit and it´s the default way. it´s included into JDK so no 3rd party tool.

Comment: Thanks Lengl for ur reply. Wants to know and try to get different or difficulties while using junit vs other tool. Which is preferable other than junit.

Comment: What are other alternative tool for mock unit Test. If possible mention it in suitable order wise.

Answer (score 1):

- jUnit
- SureAssert
- Mockito
- JS Test Driver (Like Selenium -> UI)
- Selenium (UI Testing)
- TestNG
- jTiger

Comment: Guide me to get a suitable  one. Which has more comfortable to handle. I mean which is preferable other than junit. Plz advice.

Comment: It´s depending on your skills and if you don´t now each of them you have to make your own desicion^^ try to create a simple project as a testcase and use everyting one time. Afterwards you are able to choose.
I´m focused on jUnit because it´s easy to use, very well supported, lots of documentation, included mocking and UI tests are working too. readability. help and documentation are a easy price for complexity only while writing.

Comment: Sure Lengl. Thanks for ur valuable comments.